# Regular expression: match all untill a certain word (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm processing a file with PHP.

This file contains a few blocks, which always start with the word "Step" (step 1, step 2 etc), and always end with "end step". Withing, it can have newlines, but never 2 consequently.

I'm trying to build a regex that will turn this into an array.

What I have so far is

```
preg_match_all("/Step([^\"end step\"]*)/s", $content, $matches);
```

The /s at the end of the patnern is to allow newslines to be included too. 
But of course, this does not work since all letters from "end step" are excluded, not only if they form 1 word. How can I write the correct regex?

Comment: could you post part of the file's content?

Comment: could you post an example of text you'd like to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way:

```
preg_match_all('/Step(.*?)"end step"/s', $content, $matches);
```

This matches any text from `Step` to the nearest `"end step"`. But it needs to backtrack after every single character which could be slow.

Slightly more explicit and possibly more efficient::

```
preg_match_all('/Step((?:(?!"end step").)*)/s', $content, $matches);
```

This matches all the text from `Step` up to but not including the nearest `"end step"`. It will match until the end of the string if `"end step"` never comes. This regex looks ahead at every step to check whether the string `"end step"` could be matched there and ends the match if that's true.

Comment: @user If you wonder what `?` does in that case, it simply tells the `.*` to be less greedy, and stop as soon as it finds the first `"end step"`.

Comment: The ? makes the quantifier lazy instead of greedy.. But do you care to elaborate what you're doing in the elaborate one and why that is possibly more efficient?

Comment: @barsju: Backtracking is expensive. A lookahead assertion isn't exactly cheap either, but it may well be cheaper. If it's any performance concern, one could profile it (I don't use PHP, so I don't know what the result of that comparison would be).